# Adding each index element of a list to the same index of another list but in a different format

Tags: python

Lets say I've 7 list;

```
list1 = ['1', '2', '3'] 
list2 = ['4', '5', '6'] 
list3 = ['7', '8', '9'] 
list4 = ['10','11','12'] 
list5 = ['13','14','15'] 
list6 = ['16','17','18'] 
list7 = ['19','20','21']
```

now if I want to print something like the following, how do I do that?

```
1;;;4;;;7;;;10;;;13;;;16;;;19
2;;;5;;;8;;;11;;;14;;;17;;;20
3;;;6;;;9;;;12;;;15;;;18;;;21
```

Remember, when I print the result it needs to be exactly like the printed result I've shown above. No [ ] and separated in each line. I tried the zip method but that returns [('1', '4'),('2', '5'), ('3', '6').....] and that's not what I want. Its quiet challenging isn't it?

Comment: If you have that many lists, you might want to store them in an appropriately named container list `container = [['1', '2', '3'], ..., ['19','20','21']]`, then use one of the suggestions below, passing `container` with the unpacking operator `*` to `zip`: `zip(*container)`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `zip`:

```
for t in zip(list1,list2):
    print(";;;".join(t))
```

###### Ouput:

```
1;;;4
2;;;5
3;;;6
```

Or in one line:

```
>>> print("\n".join(";;;".join([a,b]) for a,b in zip(list1,list2)))
1;;;4
2;;;5
3;;;6
```

Comment: Great answer. Just a note, if you deconstruct the tuple and reconstruct a list to pass to `join`, you could just as well leave the tuple intact and directly pass it.

Comment: What if I've like 7 list? Do I go something like for a,b,c,d,e,f,g in zip(list1,list2,list3,list4,list5,list6,list7)? I'm going to edit the question for better understanding

Comment: @fsimonjetz - Indeed, good catch. I edited :).

Comment: @Tech - See the edit. You can do `for t in zip(list1,list2,list3,list4,list5,list6,list7)`

Answer (score 1):

First you create pairs of numbers using zip:

```
>>> list(zip(list1, list2))
[('1', '4'),('2', '5'), ('3', '6')]
```

Then you apply a transformation to the output of zip to add the characters in the middle

```
>>> values = map(';;;'.join, zip(list1, list2))
>>> list(values)
['1;;;4', '2;;;5', '3;;;6']
```

Now you just need to print the result:

```
for row in values:
    print(row)
```

Which would give you the output you want:

```
1;;;4
2;;;5
3;;;6
```